# Extracting the name key in object

Tags: javascript, object

here are my var DL = 10 LL = 05

```
var service_load_combo = {
    "SL1": {
        "results": DL
    },
    "SL2": {
        "results": DL + LL,
    }
  };
```

so the results SL1.results = 10 and SL2.results = 15. Since SL2.results is biggest value of two. how could i get object name answer "SL2". i was trying the Object.key() but it's pretty hard. Hope you could help me.

Comment: Hi, where have you declared DL and LL ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/no1t0L8q/ this one

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple max algorithm, which will return the appropriate key as well. This will work on any number of `SL` entries.

```
var maxValue = Number.MIN_VALUE;
var maxKey = null;
Object.keys(service_load_combo).forEach(k => {
    var currentValue = service_load_combo[k].results;
    if (currentValue > maxValue) {
        maxValue = currentValue;
        maxKey = k;
    }
});
console.log(`Max: Key: ${maxKey} Value: ${maxValue}`);
```

If you only got 2 keys and care only for their key name, then:

```
var keys = Object.keys(service_load_combo);
var maxKey= (service_load_combo[keys[0]] > service_load_combo[keys[1]] ? keys[0] : keys[1]);
console.log(`Max: Key: ${maxKey}`);
```

Comment: Cool! i'll try that.

Comment: that $ was jquery function?

Comment: No, it's a string interpolation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var keyNames = Object.keys(myObject);
if ( keyNames.indexOf( "SL2" ) !== -1 ) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```js
let DL = 10, LL = 5;
let service_load_combo = { "SL1": {"results": DL},"SL2": {"results": DL + LL}};
 
// Setting max as 0, assuming no negative values, else can set to Number.MIN_VALUE
let max = 0, maxKey;
for (let key in service_load_combo) {
  // If the value is greater than max value, update max and maxKey
  if(service_load_combo[key].results > max) {
    max = service_load_combo[key].results ;
    maxKey =  key;
  } 
}
console.log(maxKey);
```